# SwiftUI Error occurs to call API after navigation

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swiftui

When page is moved using NavigationLink, I get this error `Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:580: Fatal error: Index out of range`. If I don't call API in child view, the program works without any errors.
The API in the child view works without navigationLink.

Let me omit some code for conciseness

Parent View

```swift
@State private var isSelection = false


var body: some View {
    NavigationLink(destination: childView(id: 123), isActive: $isSelection) { EmptyView() }

    Text("button").onTapGesture {
        self.isSelection = true
    }
}
```

Child View

```swift
@ObservedObject var viewModel = SomeThing()
let id: Int

var body: some View {
     Text("\(viewModel.message)").task {
     await viewModel.getMessage(id: id)
    }
}
```

Comment: So you have a bug in your view model?

Comment: I don't think so. The API works correctly without navigationlink.

Comment: Ok, maybe you should clarify that in the question then and explain how you access the API without a navigation link to the child view.

Comment: edited the post

Comment: This is going to need a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).